# Array of bytes[] has no values when is converted from int[]

Tags: c#

I'm passing int[] array that hold image, later I want to convert it to bytes[] and save the image to local path. However, I notice that the bytePic[] length is equal to int[] arrPic just the values are missing. There is a screenshot below:
[image: arrPic]
[image: bytePic]

Below is the entire function:

```cs
public string ChangeMaterialPicture(int[] arrPic, int materialId,string defaultPath)
{
    var material = _warehouseRepository.GetMaterialById(materialId);
    if(material is not null)
    {
        // Convert the Array to Bytes

        byte[] bytePic = new byte[arrPic.Length];
        for(var i = 0; i < arrPic.Length; i++)
        {
            AddByteToArray(bytePic, Convert.ToByte(arrPic[i]));
        }
        // Convert the  Bytes to IMG
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_.png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@$"{defaultPath}\materials\{material.VendorId}\{filename}", bytePic);

        // Update the Image
        material.Picture = filename;
        _warehouseRepository.UpdateMaterial(material);

        return material.Picture;
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

public byte[] AddByteToArray(byte[] bArray, byte newByte)
{
    byte[] newArray = new byte[bArray.Length + 1];
    bArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
    newArray[0] = newByte;
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: please explain every line in `AddByteToArray` and it's useage  (and tell as why you think that it make sens)

Comment: Rather than a screenshot and some methods, it would be *really* helpful if you'd just provide a [mcve] that we can compile/run and see the results.

Comment: I suspect the biggest problem is that you call `AddByteToArray` but ignore the return value...

Comment: To be honest I found the function on google, it supposed to extend the array with new element.

Comment: @Jon I just notice that issue... I'm not sure how to convert int[] to byte[] :\

Comment: if ints values are in range of byte then `ints.Select(i=>(byte)i).ToArray()` should do the stuff

Comment: why are you not doing `bytePic[i] = Convert.ToByte(arrPic[i])` , and remember ToByte given 8-bit unsigned integer @Maria

Comment: Please [do not use IDE screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) to show the problem. Instead, if the problem is that some variable has a wrong value at a certain point, then use code that outputs the value, and show the (text) output *as formatted text*. It's important that we can try the code ourselves and see the problem, even if we don't use your IDE. That way, we can also verify *when* the wrong value appears. Please also read [mre].

Comment: @Selvin you just saved my day! I spend 7 hours today on this issue :( Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the new array `newArray` in `AddByteToArray` and return it. But at the call site you are never using this returned value and the `bytePic` array remains unchanged.

The code in `AddByteToArray` makes no sense. Why create a new array when the intention was to insert one byte into an existing array? What you need to do is to cast the `int` into `byte`. Simply write:

```cs
byte[] bytePic = new byte[arrPic.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrPic.Length; i++)
{
    bytePic[i] = (byte)arrPic[i];
}
```

And delete the method `AddByteToArray`.

This assumes that every value in the `int` array is in the range 0 to 255 and therefore fits into one byte.

There are different ways to do this. With LINQ you could also write:

```cs
byte[] bytePic = arrPic.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your original array uses a int to represent a full RGBA-pixel, since 32bit per pixel mono images are very rare in my experience. And if you do have such an image, you probably want to be more intelligent in how you do this conversion. The only time just casting int to bytes would be a good idea is if you are sure only the lower 8 bits are used, but if that is the case, why are you using an int-array in the first place.

If you actually have RGBA-pixles you do not want to convert individual int-values to bytes, but rather convert a single int value to 4 bytes. And this is not that difficult to do, you just need to use the right methods. The old school options is to use [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Buffer_BlockCopy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Example:

```
byte[] bytePic = new byte[arrPic.Length * 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(arrPic, 0, bytePic, 0, bytePic.Length);
```

But if your write-method accepts a span you might want to just convert your array to a span and [cast this to the right type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0), avoiding the copy.